# How can I overwrite the local JSON file in my steroids js application with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a steroids js app and it uses data from a local json file in the www/data folder under **"MyApp.json"** to display things like a thumbnail image, a description etc. I want to overwrite this information upon launch of my application each time with JSON data from my server using JOSNP. I just need to know if it's possible for me to overwrite my local JSON file each time my app launches with the JSON data from my server. If so, how would I go about overwriting this file and would it work across platforms (ios, android, windows)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want a offline mode with online sync.

Best thing to do for you is to store in localStorage your javascript object

```
// json to storage 
localStorage.myList = JSON.stringify( list );
// storage to json
var list = JSON.parse( localStorage.myList );
```

The mozilla foundation have just released this weak a framework that handle different kind of online storage (asynchrounous db) :

```
https://github.com/mozilla/localForage
```

You can on each load call a refresh function that get the data from the server and store it in local, if the app is offline, directly run the script from the local database

Comment: I can't just write a script to overwrite the contents of my local JSON file?

Comment: it's way easier to load the file as a default database in a var, and manipulate it has you wish. Otherwise you'll have to check how to edit a file and all the issue with encoding :)

Comment: I need the data to be saved too though.

Comment: Then use localStorage or try localForage :)

Comment: what about this FileWriter obejct http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Comment: It's if you are using cordova API like phonegap, you'll be able to use the framework to access the file system, but if you decide to use that, keep in mind your application while depend on the framework and the device, while you have a complet solution that doesn't require such dependencies and fit perfectly you needs :)

Answer (score 0):

2this is not possible with client side javascripts, you need some sort of backend for this applicaiton - i mean a PHP script, that can change the JSON file or nodejs script.

The easiest idea is to make a PHP script and name if jsondata.php

something like it

```
if($_POST['data']){
  $handle = fopen('data.json', 'a');
  fwrite($handle, $_POST['data'])
  fclose($handle);
} else {
 readfile('data.json');
}
```

When you issue a GET call to this script, the data is given
When you issue the POST call to this script, the data is saved

Sorry, i haven't wrote scripts on PHP for about two years, so this script is lame, but i hope you got the idea